# Why method definition is optional?

Tags: c++, methods

I am not sure how this code is working. As per my understanding all declared method should be defined.

```
class Test
{
public:
void foo();
};

int main()
{
Test t;
return 0;
}
```

In class `Test`, method `foo()` is declared but not defined, still this code works fine. Please explain why this is working. Isn't it wrong to do this because only declared method is of no use unless it is in abstract class or interface ? My guess is declaration of method tells compiler about it so compiler doesn't complain about it and it will work fine until someone will actually try to use this method. If this is so, still it make no sense why this is allowed ? Is there any specific reason or use of this ?

Comment: which code you run in java ?

Comment: In C++, because you are not calling `Test::foo()`. Try `t.foo()` in `main`.

Comment: In Java this won't compile, the compiler will punch you.

Comment: sorry it didn't work in JAVA but working in c++ (http://ideone.com/oOuPvS)

Comment: @juanchopanza t.foo() will give error. I am just curious to know why like JAVA  this doesn't give compile error. Is there any specific reason for this in C++ or it's just the way language is designed.

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "works" because nothing ever calls the function `Test::foo`.

The compiler has no possible way to know if `Test` is meant to be defined in the current compile unit [1], or there is a `test.cpp` that implements the function `Test::foo`. Consequently, the compiler has to accept that you don't define the function here.

In the case where you do have two files, one with`main` and one containing `Test::foo`, this gets combined at the later, linking stage, of the compilation, when the compiler takes all the different components your software consists of and puts them together. This may be "in the future" in your learning process, but this is the reason the compiler doesn't complain about it "now". And since you don't actually try to use the function `Test::foo`, there is "no need" for it to actually exist, so no error is produced.

[1] Note that it doesn't really matter to the actual compiler if you have `class Test` in the main file, or it was included from `test.h`, since the `#include` part is dealt with before the compiler actually tries to "understand" the code.

Edit: One might of course argue here that this code is nonsense. What is the point of declaring a function that isn't used. But that is not really for the compiler/linker to decide. If you don't use something, you don't need to define it. Those are the rules.

Comment: thanks @mats so it's the linker who actually cares about linking method call with it's body not compiler. correct ?

Comment: Yes, the linker will "resolve" function calls from one compile unit (source file) to another. Until that poiint, the compiler only needs a declaration to determine that the function "exists". And the linker only resolves what is actually needed. So if you declare a function and never call it, it won't be needed by the linker. This is actually important: If you call a function in a library, which is declared along with a whole heap of other functions, you don't REALLY want all of those functions to also be dragged in if they are not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler does not complain about such a code because it can't - you could have written function definition in some other file. Only linker can tell you that there is no function definition in all of your files. But because you didn't used that function at all, there is no reference to this function, linker does not complain too.